# GIT - pushing to (GitHub) origin master does nothing

Tags: git, github

I have forked someone's GIT repository:

```
https://github.com/nippysaurus/toodledo-objc
```

Cloned it to my local machine, showing the origin with the following information:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://nippysaurus@github.com/nippysaurus/toodledo-objc.git
  Push  URL: https://nippysaurus@github.com/nippysaurus/toodledo-objc.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

When I push my changes to "origin master" git prints "everything up to date", but nothing it updated in my GitHub repo.

What is going on here?

EDIT:

Someone is suggesting that I check thay the files were actually commited... the files were commited, I assure you.

```
commit 0d3a21616d82c8e5a89baaf85d745fc2cfdf614f
Author: nippysaurus <nippysaurus@example.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 1 13:19:14 2011 +1000

    updated readme
```

This is the file that was updated:

```
commit 0d3a21616d82c8e5a89baaf85d745fc2cfdf614f
Author: nippysaurus <nippysaurus@example.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 1 13:19:14 2011 +1000

    updated readme

diff --git a/README.mdown b/README.mdown
index fb8ee14..a71aa57 100644
--- a/README.mdown
+++ b/README.mdown
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ toodledo-objc

 An _unofficial_ toodledo-API implementation in ObjectiveC.

-This library currently uses [version 1.0 of the API](http://www.toodledo.com/info/api_doc.php "Toodledo API 1.0 spec") which has been offic
+This library currently uses [version 1.0 of the API](http://www.toodledo.com/info/api_doc.php "Toodledo API 1.0 spec") which has been offic

 Supported:
```

Also, I can see that the local version of the file is very different to the version on GitHub, the changes are definately being added to my local repo, but are not being pushed to the remote repo.

Comment: What branch are you working in?  `git branch -va`

Comment: Not the master branch. Thats probably the answer! :) Anyone care to put that into an answer and I will mark as the accep[ted answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It might be the case that you are on another branch than the master branch, then type:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

so git understands that you want to push up current HEAD and not the master branch.

Answer (score 10):

When it says Up to date it means your local repository and your remote repository are one and the same, that is you have not made any changes to your local repo that needs to be pushed to the remote repo.

If you have indeed changed the files then you must have forgot to commit it.

If you had created new files then you must add it. To add files use

```
git add .
```

then to commit all the edited files use

```
git commit -am "Commit message"
```

then do

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Please format your answers using four-space indenting or backticks where appropriate. Thank you!

Comment: The file is definately being added to the commit. I have updated my original question to include this information.

Comment: In my case I indeed added the files but the next day I forgot I didn't commit the changes. Doh !

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands. Suppose `test.md` is the new file you created and you want to push it with the message "Testing"

```
$ git add test.md
$ git commit -a -m "Testing"
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: just simple do this process:- 

1)Commit your local repository for this use this command:-

git commit -am "enter updated message you want to display"

2)push changes on git

git push origin HEAD:master

if we use both command than it update all the updates changes .