# Push into master branch from Travis CI

Tags: gradle, travis-ci

I am switching from Jenkins to Travis CI.

In Jenkins, I did not have to write a script to push my Java/android library to Git master branch.

With Travis, all my research shows that I need to write a custom bash script to execute in `after_success`.

This is my `deploy.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
rev=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
git config user.name "uname"
git config user.password "password"
git add .
git commit -m "travis commit at ${rev}"
git push origin master
```

and my `.travis.yml`:

```
branches:
  only:
    - development

language: android
sudo: false

android:
  components:
    - build-tools-22.0.1
    - android-22

script:
  - cd appdir
  - ./gradlew test


after_success:
  - cd ..
  - ./deploy.sh

before_cache:
  - rm -f $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
```

Under the `script` section, I `cd` from root dir to my `appdir` and run tests from there (successfully) then in the `after_success` section, I `cd` back into root where my `deploy.sh` is located and call it.

My Travis CI console shows everything is successful but I don't see any changes in my master branch.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show logs from deploy.sh?

Comment: Please also add `git remote -v` to deploy.sh

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that Git doesn't appear know the branch your build is using and you want to push the current HEAD that has the additional commit.

In Travis CI you may have a log message just showing 'Everything up-to-date' as Git is pushing the same master branch.

You could change your script to add HEAD.

```
#!/bin/bash
rev=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
git config user.name "uname"
git config user.password "password"
git add .
git commit -m "committed at ${rev}"
git push origin HEAD:master
```

This is a similar answer that explains :- [git-pushing-to-github-origin-master-does-nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195973/git-pushing-to-github-origin-master-does-nothing).